# Partial specialization: use the primary template members

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, generic-programming

Consider

```
enum My_Enum {
    x1, x2
};

template<class T, My_Enum X>
class A {
    void f1();
    void f2();
};

template<class T>
class A<T,x1> {
    void g();
}
```

I want to use the member functions `f1()` and `f2()` of the primary template in my partially specialized template. What should I do ?

One solution would be not to do the partial specialization and then:

```
template<class T>
class AA<T> : public A<T,x1> {
    void g();
}
```

but it has the drawback that when I'm instatiating `A<T,X>`s of all sorts by generic programming, my `A<T,x1>` are no longer of type `AA<T>` and hence I cannot apply `A<T,x1>.g()`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating a base class for class A that defines those methods?

```
template <class T, My_Enum X>
class A_Base {
    void f1();
    void f2();
};

template<class T, My_Enum X>
class A : public A_Base<T, X> {
};

template<class T>
class A<T,x1> : public A_Base<T, x1> {
    void g();
};
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I possibly miss that?

Answer (score 2):

You may create a base class:

```
template<class T, My_Enum X>
class BaseA {
    void f1();
    void f2();
};

template<class T, My_Enum X>
class A : BaseA<T,X> {
};

template<class T>
class A<T,x1> : BaseA<T,x1> {
   void g();
};
```

Comment: You've got an error declaring class A - it should be `class A : BaseA<T,X>`